# How to join my custom table data to a node using nid

Tags: 7, theming, nodes, forms

My module implements a custom content type, let's say **Magazines**.
This content type will have just title and tags field in order to use taxonomy from Drupal.
I have a custom table `custom_magazines` where I store several attribute fields to the magazines.
The custom_magazines table will have a `nid` field where I reference the Drupal node.
How do I handle a form to mix the node fields (title and tags) and `custom_magazines` field?
How do I insert or update the data in both node and `custom_magazines` tables?
I'm using Drupal 7. I know about cck and eck modules, but I don't want to create an additional table for my custom attributes.
Is there an example where I can see this working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "Drupal Way" would be using fields for your additional data instead of a custom table. This would imply the following benefits:

- you could easily query the contents using entityfieldqueries or Views
- the fields would show up/being saved within your content type's edit form without any additional coding
- the additional information would load together with the content type when using node_load or node_load_multiple respectively.

However, if you'd like to stick to your architecture, you can query the database using db_select for fetching information:

```
$query = db_select('node', 'n');

$query->join('custom_magazines', 'm', 'n.nid = m.nid'); //JOIN node with magazines
$query->condition('type', 'magazines')

  ->fields('n')
  ->fields('m');

$result = $query->execute();
```

Please note that this way makes it harder to handle node information (as your taxonomy field contents) together with your additional information. You might need to load your nodes anyway or join the query with the field contents as well.

You'd also have to add the required form fields to your content type's edit form manually, and implement a custom submit callback for saving the form values to your custom table.

Additionally you should consider implementing [hook_node_insert](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_insert/7), [hook_node_update](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_update/7) and [hook_node_delete](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_delete/7) to keep your additional data in sync with your custom content type. (All steps that can be omitted using fields.)

Comment: I would have other tables for example custom_topics and custom_comments (for each magazine topic). I should follow "Drupal Way" to handle user entered data to those tables or in this case I should go my way?

Comment: That depends on the information you hold on these tables and whether you are planning to use this information with external applications as well (that directly query the same database tables). If you use the information within your Drupal only, I'd go for custom fieldable entities / bundles. This is more advanced entity usage. As beginner you can still use content types (nodes) which are fieldable by default and Entity Reference fields for storing the relations between your magazines/topics/comments.

Comment: For documentation purposes, do you think I should create my custom content type in a custom module of mine?

Comment: You always should: This will make it easier for you to migrate your content types / changes from one Drupal instance to another instance. Think of a professional workflow using development / testing / live environments, whereas you don't like to overwrite the live database or rebuild your changes within the back-end of each instance when pushing changes from one environment to the other. Instead it's advisable to create content types / alter settings via your custom module's install and update hooks. This way you have to deploy your source code only and run Drupal's update scripts.

Comment: Thank you Mario!
In the poll module I found many answers to my questions